# Jquery Mobile button only fires once

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a button that links to the current page and passes a parameter in order to indicate that the server needs to refresh a list of items on the page. It works the first time, but then subsequent clicks to not follow the href. Right now I'm simply using:

```
<a href="settings.html?refresh=1" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" data-inline="true">Refresh the list</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that is because jQuery mobile does not reload a page when it is already loaded. There is the reloadPage option that you can pass to [changePage()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/) to force a reload.

Try something like [this](http://markhildreth.me/article/forcing-page-reload-jquery-mobile):

```
<a class="force-reload" href="settings.html?refresh=1" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" data-inline="true">Refresh the list</a>
```

```
$('a.force-reload').on('click', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.mobile.changePage( url, { reloadPage: true} );
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. And thanks for including the link with the background info.